# Why do I have to wrap a closure with ()?

Tags: rust, closures

```
struct Counter<T>
where
    T: Fn() -> i32,
{
    generator: T,
    val: i32,
}

impl<T> Counter<T>
where
    T: Fn() -> i32,
{
    pub fn new(gen: T) -> Counter<T> {
        Counter {
            generator: gen,
            val: 0,
        }
    }
    pub fn next(&mut self) {
        self.val = (self.generator)(); // This works
        // self.val = self.generator(); // This does not work
    }
    pub fn get(&self) -> i32 {
        self.val
    }
}
```

The above is a small example where I am using a closure in a struct. When I call the closure via `generator()` I get `no method named generator found`. When I wrap it with `()` this does not happen. Why is that?

Comment: Why? Because these are the language's rules. You need to wrap in parentheses to call functions stored in fields.

Comment: From [ref](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/field-expr.html): Field expressions cannot be followed by a parenthetical comma-separated list of expressions,  **as that is instead parsed as a method call expression**. That is, they cannot be the function operand of a call expression.

Comment: Since `self` is a keyword, another way to look at it is that `self.generator()` is syntax sugar for `Self::generator(self)`, which obviously requires existence of a `generator` method. Parentheses just force the expression to be interpreted as the more general `foo(bar)` function call syntax without the method desugaring, which is why they do the right thing in your case. You could achieve the same result without parentheses with: `let generator = &self.generator; self.val = generator();`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Types in Rust can have both a field and a method with the same name, e.g.

```
struct Foo {
    bar: i32,
}

impl Foo {
    fn bar(&self) -> i32 {
        self.bar
    }
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Foo { bar: 42 };
    dbg!(foo.bar());
}
```

It is a [common convention to name getter methods after the field they get](https://rust-lang.github.io/api-guidelines/naming.html#getter-names-follow-rust-convention-c-getter). The Rust language designers decided to avoid conflicts between field names and method names by having separate syntax to access them. An expression of the form `foo.bar()` with parentheses always calls a method. An expression of the form`foo.bar` without directly adjacent parentheses references a field. As a consequence, you need additional parentheses around a field access expression if you want to call a function pointer stored in a field.

Comment: Thank you very much. Makes it a lot clearer.